# gradle download all dependencies from maven repo

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, artifactory

I am new at gradle
I have a question.
I use gradle and artifactory open source.
I made a repository and there are about 30 artifacts.
and I make a java project. I want to download all artifacts form the repository.
I try like this.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'repository url....'
    }
}

configurations {
    Libs
}

dependencies {
    Libs group: 'group name', id: 'artifact id', version '1.0....'
    Libs .....
}

task download(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.bxmLib
    into 'download'
}
```

I think it's heavy work...
should i specify all of artifacts like above??
Is there a way to specify that download all artifacts from repository url??

give me suggestion... thank you

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to tell gradle to download all the dependencies from a repository, you need to manually add one by one as you require as that's the point of use Gradle for dependency management.